# Binding issues of slash with quotes

Tags: php, pdo

I am using php mysql-pdo and symfony

issue is : I have a query as stated below

```
  WHERE STATUS IN (:STATUS)
```

with value of status as `A','B`.

and when i bind this as  sting its escaping as below

```
  WHERE STATUS IN ('A\',\'B')
```

and hence wrong output.

pleass help

Comment: Would you please show some PHP code (e.g. How are you preparing and binding, and the content of the being-bind variable)?

Comment: that means parameterized queries are working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepared statement can represent a **complete data literal only**. Not a part of literal, nor a complex expression, nor identifier. But either string or number only. Thus, your query doesn't work as you are actually binding a complex expression, not because of quotes

One have to create a query with placeholders representing every array member, and then bind this array values for execution:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3);
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM t WHERE id IN (?,?,?)");
$stm->execute($ids);
```

To make this query more flexible, it's better to create a string with ?s dynamically:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3);
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN ($in)";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($ids);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

Of course, if we have other variables to be bound, we need to add them to values array:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3);
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN ($in) AND category=?";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$ids[] = $category; //adding another member to array
$stm->execute($ids);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

the code become quite bloated but that's all PDO can offer to handle such complex cases. As a further improvement one can invent their own placeholders to support such complex data types.